# django rest detail_route testing

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, django-rest-framework

Good day!
I have a view with detail_route like this:

```
class PostView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    @detail_route(methods=['POST'])
    def like(self, request, pk=None):
        post = self.get_object()
        post.like(request.user)
        return Response({'result': 'success'})
```

So, url for `like` function is /api/posts/{id}/like

I try testing it with `django.test.TestCase` like this:

```
post = Post.objects.first()
url = reverse('api:post-detail', args=[post.id])
url = urljoin(url, 'like')
response = self.client.post(url, content_type='application/json', follow=True)
```

I have to use `follow=True` because I get code 300 redirect, but redirect return me GET request when I need POST.
I have tried use `APIClient` and `APIRequestFactory` and got same error or `myapp.models.DoesNotExist`
Tanks for your attention!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you get a 300 at all should be a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Rather than reversing the main URL and then joining the detail route extension manually, you should reverse directly to the full URL you want. As [the docs for `detail_route`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#extra-link-and-actions) show, that decorator gives you a named route in the form `<model>-<detail-method>`. So:

```
url = reverse('api:post-like', args=[post.id])
response = self.client.post(url, content_type='application/json')
```